# How to remove factor levels from filtered dataframe 'memory'

Tags: r

I'm subsetting a dataframe on some factor levels, only to find that the factor levels, although evaluating to 0 values, have somehow survived in the filtered dataframe as if they were retained in memory. Here's some illustrative data:

```
set.seed(121)
df1 <- data.frame(
  Fac1 = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 2),
  Fac2 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = T),
  Num = sample(1:20, 10)
)
df1
   Fac1 Fac2 Num
1     A    b  19
2     B    c  15
3     C    b  12
4     D    c   3
5     E    b   8
6     A    b   5
7     B    b   2
8     C    b   9
9     D    a  10
10    E    a  13
```

Now I remove all rows that have the values `A`on `Fac1`and, respectively, `b` on `Fac2`:

```
df2 <- df1[-which(df1$Fac1=="A" | df1$Fac2=="b"),]
```

All looks fine, the rows with these values have disappeared from the dataframe:

```
df2
   Fac1 Fac2 Num
2     B    c  15
4     D    c   3
9     D    a  10
10    E    a  13
```

**BUT** if I do for example `table`, the factor levels are still there:

```
table(df2$Fac1)
A B C D E 
0 1 0 2 1
```

How can the unwanted factor levels be removed from the filtered dataframe *for good*?

Comment: Convert to `factor` again. `df2$Fac1 <- factor(df2$Fac1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
table(droplevels(df2$Fac1))

B C D E 
1 1 1 1
```

Or applied to the whole df:

```
df2 <- droplevels(df1[-which(df1$Fac1 == "A" | df1$Fac2 == "b"), ])
```

Comment: and how to remove the unwanted factor levels from the **dataframe**?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: okay, but output of `table`should be `B D E 
1 2 1`

Comment: Your dummy data does not match your expected results. It gives the right results.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake with `set.seed`; have corrected it.